# Migration script create foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a migration script to add foreign key in the table.

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "LinkId",
                table: "a",
                nullable: false);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_a_LinkId",
                table: "a",
                column: "LinkId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_a_b_LinkId",
                table: "a",
                column: "LinkId",
                principalTable: "b",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

This helped me to create the foreign key but i see no values in the column it is showing as null. Is there anyway to get the values automatically or do i have to update the values in the foreign key column manually by using update script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the update query in the migration class

```cs
public partial class LinkIdColumn_v1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("a","LinkId",c=>c.Int());
        Sql("UPDATE SET a.LinkId= b.LinkId FROM b INNER JOIN a ON a.SomeKey = b.SomeKey");
        // Other generated code to create your FK
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
       // Generated code to drop the FK
    }
}
```